# YOLO object detection confused when see symmetrically pics

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov5, yolov4

I train some traffic signs that are symmetrically similar, then when i check signs, yolo is confused sometimes turn right sign detect as turn left. How can I resolve this problem. Is it related with  unbalance dataset or another thing?

[image: traffic sign pic.]

Comment: do you have any data augmentation in your training that flips or otherwise transforms the inputs?

Comment: yes, i add some data with apply effect

Comment: and that is the reason your network is confused: _you_ (your augmentation) tells it that those are the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, i will remove augmentation datas then train again.

Comment: you only need to remove the mirroring/flipping. translation, rotation, scaling, shearing, are all ok (and good!) as long as none of them are able to produce a mirror/flip.

Comment: why is it being augmented? why not train with data as close to what you would encounter in the real world?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The general reasons for your error case will be

1. [Data augmention](https://research.aimultiple.com/data-augmentation/#:%7E:text=strategy%20is%20important.-,What%20are%20use%20cases/examples,-in%20data%20augmentation). Remove the augmention step for your dataset. Re-train the model with raw data
2. Try to have as much as data possible for training. As per official docs, you must have 1000 images per instance in-order to have an average performing model. And also, be careful in not leading it to overfitting.